# Unable to view the encrypted image - java

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to make this code work to encrypt an image using AES algorithm and its modes, then view the encrypted image.

So the bytes of the header is not encrypted and the content was. When writing the image to the new file, the header was used first and then the encrypted content so that we can open it as an image file.

But I am unable to open it. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to coding, learning as I go :)
Thanks

```
enter code here

import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;  
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;  
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;  
import java.security.MessageDigest;  
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;  
import java.util.Arrays;  

import javax.crypto.*;  
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;  
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;  


public class test {
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey ;  
    private static byte[] key ;  
    static String encodekey = "770A8A65DA156D24EE2A093277530142";  
    static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";  

public static void main(String[] args) {

    encrypt(new File("/Users/uni/IdeaProjects/ExtendedExperimentalAPI”/src/image.jpeg"));
}

public static void encrypt(File file){
    setKey(encodekey);
    String fileName = file.getName();
    byte[] fileBytes = fileToBytes(file);
    //save the header from file so it is accessible as image after encryption
    byte[] header = new byte[55];
    for(int i = 0; i<55; i++){
        header[i] = fileBytes[i];
    }
    byte[] toEncrypt = Arrays.copyOfRange(fileBytes, 55, fileBytes.length);


    Cipher cipher;
    try {
        //block to encrypt using ECB and save file
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] cipherDataECB = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("ECB" + fileName, true);//append to file
        fos.write(header);
        fos.write(cipherDataECB);
        fos.close();

        //block to encrypt using CBC and save file
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        byte[] cipherDataCBC = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
        fos = new FileOutputStream("CBC" + fileName, true);
        fos.write(header);
        fos.write(cipherDataCBC);
        fos.close();

        //block to encrypt using CFB and save file
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        byte[] cipherDataCFB = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
        fos = new FileOutputStream("CFB" + fileName, true);//append to file
        fos.write(header);
        fos.write(cipherDataCFB);
        fos.close();

    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting file");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing to the file");
    }

}

static void setKey(String myKey){


    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting the key for encryption");
    }


}

static byte[] fileToBytes(File file){

    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    //convert file into array of bytes


    try{
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Specified file not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading from the file");
    }
    return bFile;
}
}
```

Comment: @davedwards That encrypted the entire file, which is a different question altogether. This is probably more about keeping the file format intact than anything else.

Comment: thank you @MaartenBodewes, vote retracted